# How to see variable,function other files script in ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Example:
I have file ajax demo_ajax.php will return:

```
<p>this is data in file ajax</p>
<script>
   demo();
</script>
```

And file script demo_script.js :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function demo(){
  // my code here
  }
});
```

My question is how to in file **demo_ajax.php** can call **function demo()** in file **demo_script.js**, I will try and get error function undefined

Comment: include your demo_script.js before your demo_ajax.js file then it will work

Comment: You need to call the file demo_ajax.php via demo function right ?

Comment: @Karthik Keyan yes, i have call file demo_ajax.php via script. But i not understant i have call function demo but error undefined

Comment: @danish443 I have try but not working.

Comment: exactly error is : Uncaught ReferenceError: demo is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function demo(){
  // my code here
  }
});
```

**To**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

}); 
  function demo(){
  // my code here
  }
```

Dont't forgot to include your script file on parent page

Comment: function demo() have some elated to jquery ui and jquery.

Comment: I change function demo() to top file and out $(document).ready(function(){}); this is success. thanks you,!

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(this).demo();
});
// You can replace 'this' with another selector such as 'p'
// Then inside the 'demo' function, $(this) will refer to your selector
$.fn.demo = function()
{

}
```

Comment: I have try, but error.. :( and all script no working

Answer (score 1):

include your

> demo_script.js

on the top of

> demo_ajax.php

and then it will work..